# AppendRow error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have this code in gscript and it returns me this error:

> Cannot find method appendRow(string)

The code:

```
    function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("F1");
  var string = range.getValue();
  var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("aux");
  targetsheet.appendRow(string);
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: According to the reference, it should be a string. But trying to put an object returns the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range.getValue()` returns a range, but `appendRow()` needs an array of values https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with:

```
    function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var value = sheet.getRange("F1");
  var aux = ss.getSheetByName("aux");
  value.copyValuesToRange(aux, 1, 1,aux.getLastRow() ,aux.getLastRow());

}
```

Thanks, Orangesandlemons!